# Error while implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net

When attempting to implement an interface (by right-clicking the interface and selecting "Implement Interface"), I am getting an error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> An unknown error occurred while processing.  No stubs were generated.

I tried several different interfaces but I'm getting the same error for all interfaces.

Comment: can you give some more context as in what you did ?

Comment: Have you read [the MSDN How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1s9z1w.aspx)?

Comment: This is an environmental error.  Disable add-ins one by one until you find the troublemaker.

Comment: Is the interface definition available? Do you have all patches to VS?

Comment: Have you tried to restart Visual Studio? It helps for most VS runtime errors (at least for me).

Comment: @Darthcoder, sure, I was trying to implement Interface in a class. sample below. If I build this I get an error because interface is not implemented... so when I try to implement... I get error                                                         class Class1: IEnumerable
    {

    }

Comment: @walkhard - yes, I tried restarting visual studio and and machine too... but no luck... looks like need to re-install visual studio :(

Comment: Try what Hans suggested, I've seen similar problems from add-ins.

Comment: there are a number of methods that you need to override for IEnumerable, have you done that ?? please see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx. its just that you have to extend IEnumerator as well, which people miss

Comment: @xxbbcc - interface definition is not available... when I try F12 on interface... I get message saying VS stopped working... How would I know which patch I am missing?   I have VS2010 and VS2013 on my machine.... and in both IDE's I am getting same error

Comment: @DarthCoder: This question is not about the code itself but about visual studio functionality not working as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Microsoft Visual studio or if needed restart your system(as recommended on MSDN).